# Replace specific links in Excel & Powerpoint Files across all directories & subdirectories

Tags: excel, replace, hyperlink, powerpoint

We've just migrated all our files (especially Excel and Powerpoint) from a network drive ("O:/...") to a Sharepoint site ("http://sharepoint.company.com/....").

Many of these documents still contain hyperlinks that reference to "O:/.." and need to be replaced in order to work correctly.

We're talking about 200 files, therefore the replacement process needs to be automated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, PPT can be automated.

On my PPT FAQ site, I've got the VBA code for doing the kind of search/replace on hyperlinks that you're after.

[Search/Replace for PowerPoint Hyperlinks](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00773_Batch_Search_and_Replace_for_Hyperlinks-_OLE_links-_movie_links_and_sound_links.htm)

You could modify it fairly easily into a subroutine that takes the name of a PPT file as a parameter, opens the file, performs the S/R, saves the file.  Call it from another sub that enumerates the files to be fixed.

Comment: Um.  Make that "as mentioned below".  Also, a caution:  before you can set a link to a file, the file must actually be where you say it is.  Otherwise PPT just nods happily and ignores you.  No error messages or anything else to let you know it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Excel and Powerpoint support automation. You could write a program in a variety of languages that does the thing using automation.